# Jquery link effect only works once per page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I click "contact" then "about" the animations work correctly, however, if I then click "contact" again, the animation won't work. The page appears blank.

```
$(".contact-link").click(function() {
    if ($("#contact-page-wrap").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#contact-page-wrap").slideDown(400).queue(function() {
            $(".contact-block").slideDown(400);
        });;
    } else {
        $(".about-block").slideUp(400).queue(function() {
            $(".contact-block").slideDown(400);
        });;
    }
});

$(".about-link").click(function() {
    if ($("#contact-page-wrap").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#contact-page-wrap").slideDown(400).queue(function() {
            $(".about-block").slideDown(400);
        });;
    } else {
        $(".contact-block").slideUp(400).queue(function() {
            $(".about-block").slideDown(400);
        });;
    }
});
```

How can I make it run once per click for as long as the page is open?

Comment: try using `toggle()` method instead of `slideUp/Down()` methods

Comment: I've edited the question to make the code easier to read, and replaced the Java tag with a Javascript one. Can you post the relevant HTML that accompanies this code and, optionally, create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Remove the doulbe `;` at the end of those 4 statements. Those may not be the culprit, but certainly are not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood completely your intentions, but have tou considered using .slideToggle()?

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

It is a simpler way (if I understand correctly what you're trying to do)

PS: Java is a wrong tag! You should switch it to "Javascript".

Comment: Hell my friend, [link](http://nutfilms.antibang.com/) is the site.

If you click on the links at the bottom you'll see the dilema. Initial animation is fine - the about page switches withe contact page - however the second attempt leaves it blank.

I can't seem to make slideUp or slideToggle dependent on recognizing if the other content is visible or not. Apologies for newbieness.